# Hide/Show webkit scrollbar on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make it so that the scrollbar is hidden by default using opacity and then when the user scrolls the page or hovers the scrollbar it fades in (handled by css transitions). And then when the user has stopped scrolling, the scrollbar fades out again after 1 second.

The code is:

```
/* CSS */

::-webkit-scrollbar
{
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar:hover,
.scrolling::-webkit-scrollbar
{
    opacity: 1;
}

/* JS */

$(document).ready(function(){

    var scrollingTimeout = setInterval(function(){
        $('html').removeClass('scrolling');
    }, 1000);

    $(window).scroll(function(){
        clearInterval(scrollingTimeout);
        $('html').addClass('scrolling');
    });

});
```

However the opacity doesn't seem to work? If I look in the web inspector, the style is applied, but the scrollbar is visible (regardless of whether the scrolling class is appended to the HTML tag).

Any ideas?

Comment: does `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch` work..?

Comment: Isn't that for iOS only?

Comment: Oh yes. you might want to look into some custom scroll plugins...

Comment: Not sure about opacity but I don't think even transitions would work. Check [this](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=104412). One choice would be to make the background transparent initially and change colors on hover.

Comment: Something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/t7268/) would be a bit closer to what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [jQuery Scrollbar](https://github.com/gromo/jquery.scrollbar) which is jQuery plugin, as you can see from it's name. It's cross-browser solution that based on native browser scrolling, and it is fully CSS customizable. Look at demo examples, find the one you need (I think it will be Mac OS X example) and change CSS to use transition effect.

To apply scrollbar to document, you will have to make html/body's height/width:100%, overflow:hidden, wrap your page into DIV with height/width:100% and overflow: auto, and apply scrollbar to this DIV. To make scrollbar visible during scrolling (for touch-devices, for example), use onScroll callback to add class to container/wrapper.